# Plot multiple lines from one DataFrame

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following DataFrame in Python Pandas:

```
df.head(3)

+===+===========+======+=======+
|   | year-month| cat  | count |
+===+===========+======+=======+
| 0 | 2016-01   |    1 |    14 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+
| 1 | 2016-02   |    1 |    22 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+
| 2 | 2016-01   |    2 |    10 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+
```

`year-month` is a combination of year and month, dating back about 8 years.
`cat` is an integer from 1 to 10.
`count` is an integer.

I now want to plot `count` vs. `year-month` with matplotlib, one line for each `cat`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(x='year-month', y='count', hue='cat', data=df)
```

*Note*: it might also help if you convert `year-month` to datetime type before plotting, e.g.

```
df['year-month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year-month'], format='%Y-%m').dt.to_period('M')
```